# C# - Missed file transfers with multiple FtpWebRequest using BackgroundWorker

Tags: c#, multithreading, ftp, backgroundworker, ftpwebrequest

I have a bunch of files that I am transferring to a single FTP server using C# with the FtpWebRequest object wrapped with a BackgroundWorker. This is a one-to-one relationship. So for every FtpWebRequest there is one BackgroundWorker doing the job. I fire off several of these BackgroundWorkers to send all the files I want.

The problem is that it is hit or miss. Sometimes all the files get transferred, sometimes some files are missing.

Currently I'm using a workaround where I check if the file exists on the server and if it doesn't, I try sending it again. This works, but I feel like this is a bandage over the real problem.

Stackoverflow...what do you suggest is wrong here?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't typically use BackgroundWorker, but rather tend to use Threads, Tasks, or the ThreadPool so I don't know exactly but my thoughts are, have you tried attaching to the RunWorkerCompleted event and verified that A) all the workers completed and B) they did not have failures? You could have had a situation where the FTP got them all to fast and denied some as a spam throttling technique or other such issues can happen when you rapidly fire multiple network requests all at once. I'm also unfamiliar with FtpWebRequest, but can one have multiple requests tied on so it uses one connection?

Comment: @JimmyHoffa is probably right about throttling, or your requests are going in before the server sends back an "OK" status, or you're trying to open more sockets than the server will allow.  I had a similar problem once upon a time with a PHP script that was downloading all the new files from a server, and it wasn't even multi-threaded.  You need to inspect the StatusCode and StatusDescription properties of your FtpWebResponses--there are a number of non-successful conditions that don't throw.

Comment: @JimmyHoffa, please put your comment as an answer so I can vote for it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't typically use BackgroundWorker, but rather tend to use Threads, Tasks, or the ThreadPool so I don't know exactly but my thoughts are, have you tried attaching to the RunWorkerCompleted event and verified that A) all the workers completed and B) they did not have failures? You could have had a situation where the FTP got them all to fast and denied some as a spam throttling technique or other such issues can happen when you rapidly fire multiple network requests all at once. I'm also unfamiliar with FtpWebRequest, but can one have multiple requests tied on so it uses one connection?